# How to get the number of Bitcoin transactions every 30mins using API in python?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, api, python

I'd like to get number of Bitcoin transactions every 30 minutes using API in python.

Does someone know sample code how to mount in Github or any website?

Comment: This question is a little vague, and should probably be changed if you want any answers.  You should probably ask this in two separate questions.  First, how to count transactions per half hour on the Bitcoin network.  After that is answered, post another question asking about a python library that can help with whatever the answer to the first question was.  That will likely yield better answers than the current question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the blockchain.info api (https://blockchain.info/api) and then track in your database the different number of transactions based on any time you would like.